# Campo Identity indo no Insert

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Quando faço meu `insert` da tabela empresas o campo EmpresaCodigo (Campo identity) esta indo no `insert`, mesmo a propriedade dele estando como `Identity` na minha aplicação asp.net. 
O que posso fazer ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class EmpresaController : System.Web.UI.Page

{

    Entities context = new Entities();

public void Insert ()

{

        empresa.EmpAtivo = empAtivo;
        empresa.EmpData = empData;
        empresa.EmpMF = empMF;
        empresa.EmpRazao = empRazao;
        empresa.EmpFantasia = fantasia;
        empresa.EmpEndereco = empEndereco;
        empresa.EmpNumero = empNumero;
        empresa.EmpComp = empComp;
        empresa.EmpBairro = empBairro;
        empresa.EmpCidade = empCidade;
        empresa.EmpEstado = empEstado;
        empresa.EmpPais = empPais;
        empresa.EmpCep = empCep;
        empresa.EmpCNPJ = empCNPJ;
        empresa.EmpIE = empIE;
        empresa.EmpMunicipal = empMunicipal;
        empresa.EmpCPF = empCPF;
        empresa.EmpFone = empFone;
        empresa.EmpCel = empCel;
        empresa.EmpEmail = empEmail;
        empresa.EmpMunicipio = empMunicipio;
        empresa.EmpNire = empNire;
        empresa.EmpCnae = empCnae;
        empresa.EmpLogo = null;
        empresa.EmpObs = empObs;            

        context.Empresas.Add(empresa);
        context.SaveChanges();

  }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi o "Está indo no Insert". Quando uma tabela possui um campo identity, você não precisa incluí-lo explicitamente, mas isso você já sabe e quando se faz o Insert, ele é disparado. Mesmo que haja rollback, para o caso de transações, mesmo assim ele já foi disparado, "queimando" aquele valor. Pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Cara brigadão pela disponibilidade, mas acabei resolvendo aqui. No banco de dados criaram o campo como numeric, pelo que entendi o visual studio não estava reconhecendo que o campo era identity. Mudei no banco pra int e no model e funcionou normalmente.

Comment: Legal que achou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No banco de dados criaram o campo como numeric, pelo que entendi o visual studio não estava reconhecendo que o campo era identity. Mudei no banco pra int e no model e funcionou normalmente.